Why do the BG test results seem contradictory
I conducted a Breusch-Godfrey (BG) test after performing a regression, and the results showed that the p-value was 0.12, indicating that there is no serial correlation. However, the two-time lagged error was highly significant in the auxiliary regression. Why?

The Breusch-Godfrey is a portmanteau-type test; it looks at multiple lags jointly. It is entirely possible that one lag is significant on its own, yet the entire group of lags considered in the BG test are not jointly significant. E.g. you may be testing 20 lags, and one of them turns out to be statistically significant. This is completely in line with the joint null hypothesis tested at a 5% level; on average across the possible samples, 1 out of 20 lags should be statistically significant purely by chance. Hence, there is no contradiction. (For a related issue, see also my answer in this thread.)

So, when I encounter such a case, how can I determine if autocorrelation exists? By the way, when I run the Breusch-Godfrey (BG) test, I set the maximum lag length to 2.

@XuYang, it depends on what exactly you are interested in (which autocorrelations, individually or as a group). As you have noted, slightly different questions may yield different answers.

I just used time series to perform the regression, not panel data. Thanks again.

@XuYang, what do you want to tell us by that? None of my points rely on the assumption of the data being panel data.
